# C++ constexpr std::array of string literals

Tags: c++, stl

I've been happily using the following style of constant string literals in my code for awhile, without really understanding how it works:

```
constexpr std::array myStrings = { "one", "two", "three" };
```

This may seem trivial, but I'm hazy on the details of what is going on under the hood. From my understanding, class template argument deduction (CTAD) is used to construct an array of the appropriate size and element type. My questions would be:

1. What is the element type of the std::array in this case, or is this implementation specific? Looking at the debugger (I'm using Microsoft C++), the elements are just pointers to non-contiguous locations.
2. Is it safe to declare constexpr arrays of string literals in this way?

I could do this instead, but it's not as tidy:

```
const std::array<std::string, 3> myOtherStrings = { "one", "two", "three" };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [user17732522 already noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71882832/364696), the type deduction for your original code produces a `const std::array<const char*, 3>`. This works, but it's not a C++ `std::string`, so every use needs to scan for the `NUL` terminator, and they can't contain embedded `NUL`s. I just wanted to emphasize the suggestion from my comment to use `std::string_view`.

Since `std::string` inherently relies on run-time memory allocation, you can't use it unless the *entirety* of the associated code is also `constexpr` (so no actual `string`s exist at all at run-time, the compiler computes the final result at compile-time), and that's unlikely to help you here if the goal is to avoid unnecessary runtime work for something that is partially known at compile time (especially if the `array` gets recreated on each function call; it's not global or `static`, so it's done many times, not just initialized once before use).

That said, if you can rely on C++17, you can split the difference with `std::string_view`. It's got a very concise literal form (add `sv` as a prefix to any string literal), and it's fully `constexpr`, so by doing:

```
// Top of file
#include <string_view>
// Use one of your choice:
using namespace std::literals; // Enables all literals
using namespace std::string_view_literals; // Enables sv suffix only
using namespace std::literals::string_view_literals; // Enables sv suffix only

// Point of use
constexpr std::array myStrings = { "one"sv, "two"sv, "three"sv };
```

you get something that involves no runtime work, has most of the benefits of `std::string` (knows its own length, can contain embedded `NUL`s, accepted by most string-oriented APIs), and therefore operates more efficiently than a C-style string for the three common ways a function accepts string data:

1. For modern APIs that need to read a string-like thing, they accept `std::string_view` by value and the overhead is just copying the pointer and length to the function
2. For older APIs that accept `const std::string&`, it constructs a temporary `std::string` when you call it, but it can use the constructor that extracts the length from the `std::string_view` so it doesn't need to prewalk a C-style string with `strlen` to figure out how much to allocate.
3. For any API that needs a `std::string` (because it will modify/store its own copy), they're receiving `string` by value, and you get the same benefit as in #2 (it must be built, but it's built more efficiently).

The only case where you do worse by using `std::string_view`s than using `std::string` is case #2 (where if the `std::array` contained `std::string`s, no copies would occur), and you only lose there if you make several such calls; in that scenario, you'd just bite the bullet and use `const std::array myStrings = { "one"s, "two"s, "three"s };`, paying the minor runtime cost to build real `string`s in exchange for avoiding copies when passing to old-style APIs taking `const std::string&`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is CTAD deducing the template arguments for you. (since C++17)

`std::array` has a [deduction guide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/deduction_guides) which enables CTAD with this form of initializer.

It will deduce the type of `myStrings` to

```
const std::array<const char*, 3>
```

The `const char*` is the result of usual array-to-pointer decay being applied to the elements of the initializer list (which are arrays of `const char`s).

`const` in front is a consequence of `constexpr`.

Each element of the array will point to the corresponding string literal.

`constexpr` is safe and you can use the array elements as you would individual string literals via `const char*` pointer. In particular trying to modify these literals or the array via `const_cast` will have undefined behavior though.

`const std::array<std::string, 3>` also works, but will not be usable in constant expressions. `constexpr` is not allowed on this because of `std:string`.

CTAD can also be used to deduce this type though with the help of string literal operators:

```
#include<string>
using namespace std::string_literals;

//...

const std::array myOtherStrings = { "one"s, "two"s, "three"s };
```

or since C++20:

```
const auto myOtherStrings = std::to_array<std::string>({ "one", "two", "three" });
```

Comment: [`operator""s` for `std::string` is `constexpr` since C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) so presumably `constexpr` could be used with a new enough compiler. Or since C++17, they could use `sv` suffix to make them all `std::string_view` literals (which were `constexpr` from the start).

Comment: @ShadowRanger It is usable inside constant expressions since C++20, but you still can't have a constant-initialized `std::string`, so `constexpr` still won't work. `std::string_view`/`sv` will work as an alternative similar to `const char*` adding size information and can be `constexpr`.

Comment: I'll buy that (haven't used/grok-ed modern `constexpr` enough, and `std::string` does seem a weird one for it to work in general, given the inherently runtime nature of memory allocation for the data, ignoring the SSO). But yeah, in real code, as long as the users aren't going down to the NUL-terminated C-style string level, I just put the `sv` prefix on everything; why make everything that uses it compute the length (or repeatedly check for NUL as it traverses the string) when you can bake the length in at compile-time and avoid every runtime `strlen` check?